# Returning Enum from function where enum has duplicate values

Tags: python, enums

I have a enumeration to represent different possible values of a function.

```
class A(Enum):
    NOT_FOUND = NONE
    INAQUATE = NONE
    POSITIVE = 1
    # Some more
```

However, when returning this enumeration from a function,

```
def search_function(target = 1):
    if target == 1:
        return A.INAQUATE
    else:
        return A.POSITIVE
```

returns `A.NOT_FOUND`, not `A.INAQUATE` which breaks the program down the line.

Python 3.7.6

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class A(Enum):
...     NOT_FOUND = None
...     INAQUATE = None
...     POSITIVE = 1
... 
>>> def search_function(target = 1):
...     if target == 1:
...             return A.INAQUATE
...     return A.NOT_FOUND
... 
>>> search_function()
<A.NOT_FOUND: None>
```

Is there a way to properly return `A.INAQUATE`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Enums with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537316/python-enums-with-duplicate-values)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that it is unrelated as only the return value is my concern. I have overridden comparison operators and the only problem at the moment is the wrong return value from this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Enum`s have duplicate values, the members are the exact same object -- just referenced by both names in the `Enum` itself:

```
>>> list(A)
[<A.NOT_FOUND: None>, <A.POSITIVE: 1>]

>>> A.INAQUATE is A.NOT_FOUND
True
```

The easiest solution is give each member a unique value.  The next easiest solution is to use the `aenum` library<sup>1</sup>:

```
from aenum import Enum, NoAlias

class A(Enum):
    #
    _settings_ = NoAlias
    #
    NOT_FOUND = None
    INAQUATE = None
    POSITIVE = 1
```

And in use:

```
>>> list(A)
[<A.INAQUATE: None>, <A.NOT_FOUND: None>, <A.POSITIVE: 1>]

>>> A.INAQUATE is A.NOT_FOUND
False
```

**NB** When using `NoAlias` enumerations the lookup-by-value functionality is lost:

```
>>> A(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: NoAlias enumerations cannot be looked up by value
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: This is interesting. Any particular reason why standard enum has been implemented this way?

Comment: Because `Enum` is meant to give a name to a value -- if you have more than one member assigned to the same value then some of the usefulness is lost.  Oh, I forgot to mention: `NoAlias` enumerations can be looked up by value -- `A(1)` raises a `TypeError`.