# Printing all member names of a enum class

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

```
class MyValues(enum.Enum):
    value1 = 1
    value2 = 2
    value3 = 1

print(MyValues._member_names_)
```

Output would be a list with only the first two members [value1,value2]

I would also like to have value3 in that list, i tried with aenum with NoAlias setting but did not work.
Is there any way to get all members even if they have duplicate values?

Comment: You can use `MyValues.__members__` to get a dictionary of name-Enum mapping. So to get only the names, you'd do `list(MyValues.__members__)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Enums with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537316/python-enums-with-duplicate-values)

Comment: WHY did you give duplicate values to enum??!?!

Comment: @PersianMan: because sometimes a single value can have different names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_member_names_` is not part of the Enum documented public API. You should not use it.

[`__members__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-dunder-names) is what you're looking for. It's a mapping from member names to members, including all aliases. You can use `list(MyValues.__members__)` if you just want a list of the names.