# for loop is not printing all defined enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Defined an Enum, where I want to verify mapping of the key from db1 with db2. While iterating using for loop it doesn't print all the defined enums..

```
from enum import Enum

class SecData(Enum):
    secId = "sectoId"
    anteName = "anteName"
    rAzimuth = "rAzimuth"
    agl = "AboveGroundLevel"
    actualAzimuth = "AntennaHeight"
    actualLatitude = "SectorLat"
    technology = "technology"
    antennaType = "sectorAntennaType"
    actualElectricalTilt = "sectorElecTilt"
    actualMechanicalTilt = "sectorMechTilt"
    sectorNumber = "sectorNum"
    rtsTilt = "rtsTilt"
    band = "sectorBand"
    actualLongitude = "SectorLong"
    actualAntennaheight = "sectorAntennaHeight"
    siteReferenceId = "null"
    retiid4 = "null"
    retiid2 = "null"
    retiid3 = "null"
    NominalId = "null"
    retiid1 = "null"
    status = "null"



for sector in (SecData):
    print(sector.name, "-" , sector.value)
```

Output

```
secId - sectoId
anteName - anteName
rAzimuth - rAzimuth
agl - AboveGroundLevel
actualAzimuth - AntennaHeight
actualLatitude - SectorLat
technology - technology
antennaType - sectorAntennaType
actualElectricalTilt - sectorElecTilt
actualMechanicalTilt - sectorMechTilt
sectorNumber - sectorNum
rtsTilt - rtsTilt
band - sectorBand
actualLongitude - SectorLong
actualAntennaheight - sectorAntennaHeight
siteReferenceId - null
```

Can someone help to identify what's the issue with the script?

Comment: Your values are not unique. You have multiple `null` values so other `null` values are skipped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Enums with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537316/python-enums-with-duplicate-values)

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)

> Enum is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique values

The enum value should have different value. In you case you have more than one null value.

So other null value has no effect in your code.

```
    siteReferenceId = "null"
    retiid4 = "null"
    retiid2 = "null"
    retiid3 = "null"
    NominalId = "null"
    retiid1 = "null"
    status = "null"
```

Answer (score 1):

All the members with a "null" value are aliases of each other.

As stated at [the start of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

> An enumeration:
>
> - [...]
> - can be iterated over to return its canonical (i.e. non-alias) members in definition order

So aliased members are essentially folded into one item for iteration purposes. Which is why you only see `siteReferenceId` being printed (the first "null" member).

If wanted, you can avoid aliases with [the verify dectorator and the UNIQUE argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.EnumCheck.UNIQUE).